# Allow Public IP Access to UbuntuServer on VM

Tags: ubuntu, ip, webserver, lamp

I have set up LAMP on UbuntuServer16 which is inside a VirtualMachine VMware Workstation Player 12 (non-commercial) on Windows10.

My local ip address on the UbuntuServer is `192.168.ab.xyz`

And my public ip address which I was able to get through: 
`curl icanhazip.com` is `213.205.abc.xyz`

When I browse to `http://192.167.ab.xyz/` I can see that it works!

However, when I go to `http://213.205.abc.xyz` it shows that it took too long to respond!

I'm still a newb. I have read that I need to config my WiFi router (Technicolor TG582n) to fix this but there's another problem because I don't have the password of it to check its settings. I should probably contact my administrator.

I still haven't bought a domain name if that matters.

I followed this tutorial to set up the LAMP stack: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04

My question:

- Should I connect to the WiFi router and configure it? If yes, then I will contact the router admin but is there any tutorial for configuring the router to resolve this issue (I couldn't find any)
- If not, then what should I do to access my web server from its public ip address?

Comment: You didn't mention which hypervisor you're using.  Is it Virtualbox, or something else?  Also, is your Windows 10 machine connected directly to the internet, or do you have some kind of router between your modem and the computer?

Comment: You'll need to forward a port in your router, and your router will need to support hairpin NAT to be able to use the external address from inside the LAN.  Since you didn't include any information about the router, other than that you can't access it or change anything anyway, then I'm not sure what you're expecting from us? Go talk to your router admin. And if help is still needed, come back with more details, including what you've tried already.

Comment: @CharlesBurge I'm using VMware Workstation 12 Player (non-commercial), and the host is is connected through WiFi to a router which is also a DSL modem which is connected directly to the ISP

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 what I wanted to hear is that yes I need to configure the WiFi router and therefore I will ask for its login form the admin

Comment: Yes you need to get in the router and do some port forwarding eg: port 80 to the IP of your VM.

Answer (score 0):

[Technicolor TG582n - Help & Support](https://www.spark.co.nz/help/internet-data/equipment/technicolour/technicolor-tg582n-help-and-support/)

[Technicolor TG582n User Manual](https://www.spark.co.nz/content/dam/kb/private/attachments/13731/TG582n_User_Guide_UPADTED.pdf)

Page 68 (Assign a game or application to a local networking device) has the answer to your question for port forwarding.

You need to forward service "HTTP Server (World
Wide Web)." as described in step 4 of the manual to your Ubuntu server "192.168.ab.xyz"

If you are doing this from home, you might take a look at page 69 "Dynamic DNS" in case you have a dynamic IP. (Will change if your router restarts).

You don't need to buy a domain name. You can access via public IP directly, or in case of Dynamic DNS you will have a URL assigned to you. Usually for free.

Comment: okI will get the username and password for the router to login and configure it. and get back to you in the coming days